# Select First N from Cassandra Column using CQL

Tags: cassandra, cql

How to get First N columns of a given row key in Cassandra?

```
cqlsh> select FIRST 5 from Daily_Domain_Stats where KEY = '20111110:1';
Bad Request: line 1:15 no viable alternative at input 'from'
cqlsh> select 'FIRST' 5 from Daily_Domain_Stats where KEY = '20111110:1';
Bad Request: line 1:15 no viable alternative at input '5'
cqlsh> select 'FIRST 5' from Daily_Domain_Stats where KEY = '20111110:1';
cqlsh> select FIRST '5' from Daily_Domain_Stats where KEY = '20111110:1';
Internal application error
cqlsh> select 5 from Daily_Domain_Stats where KEY = '20111110:1';
cqlsh> select [FIRST 5] from Daily_Domain_Stats where KEY = '20111110:1';
Bad Request: line 1:15 no viable alternative at character ']'
```

I tried all these ways but nothing gave me the proper result. Im using cql 1.0.5 Python client

Help
Regards, Tamil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution,

```
cqlsh> select first 5 '0'..'9' from Daily_Customer_Stats;
```

This worked

Reference http://www.slideshare.net/jericevans/cql20

Comment: Why? I don't understand what the '0'..'9' represents and I continue to get the errors you specify above.

Comment: This was answered when cassandra was at 0.8.0 I hope.. Can you check the docs for latest?

Comment: Apparently this is no longer supported in CQL 3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30571744/89590